# How can I present a UIViewController on top of another UIViewController, but not taking up the full screen

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

[image: Required final image]I am writing a custom `UIStoryboardSegue` and I intend to present a the Destination ViewController over the Source ViewController, with animation. Here is the code for the animation

```
    override func perform() {
        let topVCView = self.destination.view
        let bottomVCView = self.source.view

        let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width
        let screenHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height

        topVCView!.frame  = CGRect(x: 0.0 - screenWidth, y: 0, width: 150.0, height: screenHeight)

        let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow
window?.insertSubview(topVCView!, aboveSubview: bottomVCView!)
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
            topVCView!.frame = topVCView!.frame.offsetBy(dx: screenWidth, dy: 0.0)
        }, completion: ({(finished) -> Void in


        }))

    }
```

The animation works gracefully enough. But I cannot get callback on `UIButton` actions in my destinationVC. How can I get that to work?

Edit: The red VC is my source VC and the green one is my destination VC

Comment: is there any error when you click button on on destination view controller

Comment: No errors. I just don't get the control over to the action of the Button

Comment: have you added destination controller as child view controller ?

Comment: no i haven't. How would the code go?

Answer (score 0):

```
override func perform() {
            let contentVC = self.sourceViewController;
            let sideBarVC = self.destinationViewController;

            var sideFrame = sideBarVC.view.frame

            sideBarVC.view.frame = CGRect(x: -(contentVC.view.frame.size.width), y: 0, width: contentVC.view.frame.size.width/2, height: contentVC.view.frame.size.height)

            sideFrame = sideFrame.offsetBy(dx: -1 * contentVC.view.frame.size.width, dy: 0)
            contentVC.view.superview?.addSubview(sideBarVC.view)

            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
                sideBarVC.view.frame = sideFrame
                contentVC.view.alpha = 0.5
            }
        }
```

Comment: I tried that. But, that would present the destination viewcontroller to full screen. That is not what i want

Comment: means you want modal ?

Comment: I'll attach the image of my required screen

Comment: that didn't help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160105/discussion-between-sidharth-j-dev-and-nikunj-damani).

Comment: now what is the issue you are facing with this code ?